# What does 10** mean in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have to convert a code from Fortran to R and I don't know how what this statement means

```
KB = 10.0**(-(1030.5/(273.15 + T) + 5.5076 - 0.015469*S + 1.5339D-4*S**2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** is the exponentiation operator in Fortran.  10**2 == 100.

Comment: No problem.  This is a pretty easy look up in any fortran manual, though, which is why people are down voting the question.  In the future, you might look in the manual before asking on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Exponentiation, for example:

```
4 ** 2 = 4 * 4 = 16
2 ** 5 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 32
```